# Problem with installing ROS indigo Ubuntu 14.04 - ros-indigo-perception

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I already installed ROS-indigo once on my Ubuntu 14.04 which was working perfectly but I was obliged to delete ROS-indigo.

Now that I am trying to re-install ROS-indigo it does not accept the full desktop version installation and gives me this error

> $ sudo apt-get install
> ros-indigo-desktop-full
>
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building  dependency tree
> Reading state  information... Done
> Some packages  could not be installed.
> This may mean  that you have requested
> an impossible  situation or if you are
> using the  unstable distribution that
> some required packages have not yet
> been  created or been moved out of
> Incoming.  The following information
> may help to  resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet
> dependencies:  ros-indigo-desktop-full
> : Depends: ros-indigo-perception but
> it is not going to be installed E:
> Unable to correct problems, you have
> held broken packages.

I searched on the previous answers and nothings works and still it has a problem with the "ros-indigo-perception"

Thanks,
Hamed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271737/problem-with-installing-ros-indigo-ubuntu-14.04----ros-indigo-perception/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2017-09-28**:
I should mention that I tried Synaptic and

> $sudo apt-get install -f

In order to fix the broken packages, but still is not working.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-28**:
Please note that updates to your question (and answers) should be done as an edit to your question and *not* as an answer.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-28**:
How did you delete ROS? What answers did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

make sure your system is up to date

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

---

Originally posted by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) with karma: 68 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0